# Android - MinSdkVersion recognized as TargetSdkVersion

Tags: android, cordova

Since november 2018 Google wants all apps and updates for app to target at least Android 8.0 (API level 26) https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/target-sdk.

Currently, I am developing an app using Cordova 8.1.2 and my build.gradle is set as follows:

```
project.ext {
  defaultBuildToolsVersion="27.0.1" //String
  defaultMinSdkVersion=21 //Integer - Minimum requirement is Android 5.0
  defaultTargetSdkVersion=28 //Integer - We ALWAYS target the latest by default
  defaultCompileSdkVersion=28 //Integer - We ALWAYS compile with the latest by default
}
```

Everything is running correctly, but when I upload the .apk-file to the play store, I get the following error:

```
Your app is currently targeting API level 21 and must target at least API level 26 to ensure the app is based on the latest APIs that are optimized for security and performance. Change the target API level of your app to at least 26. More information: https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/target-sdk.
```

I do not want to upgrade to API level 26, because a lot of my current users will not get any updates anymore. So what can i do?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: could you please translate the text that you are getting in the error(screenshot)

Comment: I have the same problem before , So i change the targetSdkVersion to 26 , and create new ScreenShoot for the apps after everting ok for me

Comment: @ChandraniChatterjee My bad. Here is the translation:
Your app is currently targeting API level 21 and must target at least API level 26 to ensure the app is based on the latest APIs that are optimized for security and performance. Change the target API level of your app to at least 26. [More information](https://developer.android.com/distribute/best-practices/develop/target-sdk).

Comment: *So what can i do?* - file a bug report with cordova